# How do I iterate over all touch event properties in the TouchList for a touch event in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, touch-event

I am trying to understand touch events, but I cannot get anything to work.

I have a very simple page to test this:

**HTML**:

```
<div id="TOUCHME"> TOUCH ME </div>
<div id="OUTPUT"></div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
const TOUCHME = document.getElementById('TOUCHME');
const OUTPUT = document.getElementById('OUTPUT');

TOUCHME.addEventListener('touchstart',(evt)=>{
    evt.preventDefault();
    let touches = evt.touches;
    for(let i=0; i<touches.length; i++){
        let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
        newDiv.appendChild(document.createTextNode(touches[i]));
        OUTPUT.appendChild(newDiv);
    }
});
```

However, as you can guess, nothing shows up. I even referenced MDN and they have an almost identical **[example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events#example)**.

I found some information here on **[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9585487/cant-get-coordinates-of-touchevents-in-javascript-on-android-devices)**, but they say do something like this:

```
var touch = event.touches[0];
var x = touch.pageX;
var y = touch.pageY;
```

This does work, but what if a person doesn't know that `touch[0]` is what you need to access? Aside from scouring MDN, how is a person supposed to know all the properties of `touch[0]` unless they can iterate over the `TouchList`?

I also tried this:

```
Object.entries(evt.touches)
```

and

```
Object.entries(evt.touches[0])
```

But neither of those worked either; meaning I couldn't iterate over any list as their sizes are always `0`.

So, how does a person iterate over the `TouchList` of touch properties for a touch?

Answer (score 0):

You have to access the [properties of the Touch event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch#basic_properties) directly; destructuring assignments don’t seem to work here.

```js
  const TOUCHME = document.getElementById('TOUCHME');
  const OUTPUT = document.getElementById('OUTPUT');

  TOUCHME.addEventListener('touchstart', (evt) => {
    evt.preventDefault();
    let touches = evt.touches;
    for (i = 0; i < touches.length; i++)
      OUTPUT.appendChild(
        document.createTextNode(
          touches.item(i).identifier + " "
        )
      )
  });
```

```html
<div id="TOUCHME"> TOUCH ME </div>
<div id="OUTPUT"></div>
```

(i) If you are using a no-touch device, make sure to activate the touch simulation in your dev tools. For example, in Firefox this is done here: https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/responsive_design_mode/#controlling-responsive-design-mode (search for “Enable/Disable touch simulation”)

Comment: So there's no way to "blindly" iterate over the `TouchList` in order to get all the properties?